# This code prevents my form from submitting (only in chrome, works in IE and Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, submit

I have this code which simply disables all the submit buttons and alla AJAX links on my page after i click on a submit. I clone the clicked event so that server side i know what submit has been pressed. This works perfectly on IE and Firefox but on chrome it refuses to submit anything. it seem that it prevents submit, as i see that the clone is inserted correctly in the DOM and no errors are logged in the console.

```
// Block all other submit and ajax requests. The subscribe users burron is avoided because it handles this by itself
$( 'input[type=submit]' ).not( '#ai1ec_subscribe_users' ).click( function() {
    block_all_submit_and_ajax( this );
} );
// Disables all submit buttons after a submit button is pressed.
var block_all_submit_and_ajax = function( el ) {
    // Clone the clicked button, we need to know what button has been clicked so that we can react accordingly
    var $clone = $( el ).clone();
    // Change the type to hidden
    $clone.attr( 'type', 'hidden' );
    // Put the hidden button in the DOM
    $( el ).after( $clone );
    // Disable all submit button.
    $( '#facebook input[type=submit]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
    // unbind all click handler from ajax
    $( '#facebook a.btn' ).unbind( "click" );
    // Disable all AJAX buttons.
    $( '#facebook a.btn' ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    } );
}
```

EDIT apparently the problem lies with the line

```
$( '#facebook input[type=submit]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );
```

because if i comment that it works also in chrome. I'm using jQuery 1.6 (but it's a wordpress plugin so the verison might vary)

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Your browser will send the name/value pair of the form button that was pressed to submit. You can simply use this to tell the server which button was pressed to submit. You do not need to rely on javascript for this.

Comment: can u provide the html please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your button is disable the form is not submitted add a setTimeOut to change the tread and I will work something like

```
 setTimeout(function() {
$( '#facebook input[type=submit]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );

},0);
```

it works even with 0 as time for the timeout

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML it's hard to say.. You may want to mess with the selector.  You can try multiple things:

```
  $("#facebook [type=submit]").attr('disabled',true);
```

or even

```
  $("[type=submit]").attr('disabled',true);
```

Because maybe you have it as a `<button>` instead of an `<input>` ?

```
  $("#facebook button[type=submit]").attr('disabled',true);
```